# GWT DockLayoutPanel gap between cells

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I'm using a DockLayoutPanel as my main layout widget for my GWT app. I have a north and center.

Problem is there is about a 5 px gap between them. I've changed the borders, margins and padding of the DockLayoutPanel to 0 but it's still there. I'm using UiBinder and when I go to the visual editor I see the gap but can't click it, it's infuriating. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your .ui.xml file contents.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the offending elements using either Firebug or WebKit Inspector, to see how the layout of the two panels has been determined? It seems likely there is CSS declaration other than those you've been looking at so far that has an effect on this - and the Style panel in Firebug would give you some insight on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of dirty but I switched to a HeaderPanel and it worked. I used dock originally as there was a side bar at one point but that's gone now. The lesson here is to re-assess your solution when the requirements change, even if it's a quick head shake.

Thanks for the help to everyone that responded.